# Understanding Different definition of Balanced Set

Tags: functional-analysis, definition

Hi I am learning functional analysis via the lectures notes of someone I know.  His professor has a less common definition of "Balanced Set", so I am checking my understanding:

> A neighborhood $X$ of $0$ is said to be *balanced* if for every $x\in X$ and $r \in [0,1]$, we have $rx \in X$.

Using the cartesian plane $\mathbb{R}^2$ as my intuition, I would interpret a balanced neighborhood $X$ of $0$ to be any neighborhood that contains whole line segments connecting $(0,0)$ to points $(x,y) \in X$.

I am ok so far.  But then the lectures state this, which looks like the usual definition:

> This is equivalent to saying that $X$ is *balanced* if for every $x\in X$ and $|r| \leq 1$, we have $rX \subseteq X$

The first definition seems like a so called "Star Domain", and the 2 don't seem equivalent. Right?

Comment: The difference appears to be that one characterization requires $r\ge0$ and the other does not.

Comment: But they are not equivalent right? That difference on restriction of $r$ changes the story quite a bit

Comment: It appears that they ought to have said $r\in[-1,1]$ rather than $r\in[0,1],$ since in the latter case, the word "balanced" does not seem to make sense.